# magento - custom attribute display on configurable products

Tags: php, magento

i'm trying to change the way customizable products display on frontend. Instead of filtering attributes by a dropdown like this :

[image: dropdown]

i want to do it via a radio button, like this :

[image: radio list]

unfortunately, the dropdown is filled with JS, in js/varien/product.js . The cart update with the right product must be in this JS file too. Does anyone know if it's possible to modify this display without breaking the cart update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the below links.

[Inchoo configurable products dropdown modification](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/configurable-product-modification-in-magento/)

[Magento thread](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/10396/)

Comment: Wow, the inchoo post looks exactly like what i want, i'll try it and give you feedback. Thanks

Comment: inchoo module did it perfectly. Thanks 1000 time, i spent many time on this